# How can i retrieve and override presets chart.js option in angular selector?

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I'm setting up some data with multiple chart.js on the same line. Now, for reason of law spaces in responsive mode, i need to override the default presets option, so i can hide the yAxes, that is not useful for my needs.

In my application write in Angular 7, I've implemented chart.js library, and the type, like data, are implemented directly in the selector.

So this is where I started:

Default Step in my component.ts:

```
export class ChartJsComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @Input() public data:any;
  @Input() public type:string;
  @Input() width:string = '100%';



  constructor(private el:ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {

    let ctx = this.getCtx();
    let data = this.data;

    if(data.datasets && data.datasets.length && presets[this.type] && presets[this.type].dataset){
      data.datasets =  data.datasets.map((it)=>{
        return Object.assign({}, presets[this.type].dataset, it)
      })
    }

    let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: this.type,
      data: data,
      options: presets[this.type] ? presets[this.type].options : {}
    });
    chart.update();

  }
```

I've tried an update:

```
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: this.type,
      data: data,
      options: presets[this.type] ? presets[this.type].options : {
        scales: {
          yAxes: {
            display: false
          }
        }
      }
    });
    chart.update();
```

I've tried this approach also in my component.html:

```
<sa-chart-js
  type="pie"
  [data]="{//omitted}"
  [options]="[{
    scales:{
      yAxes:{
        display: false
      }
    }
   }]">
</sa-chart-js>
```

but nothing seems to work.

I want override the option directly in my selector but, at today I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The `xAxes` and `yAxes` properties are arrays since chart.js supports having multiple axes for each. You will need to change your code to be an array of axis objects instead of an object.

```js
yAxes: [{
  display: false
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've tried, but nothing works, because I'don't to retrieve the options inside selector